# How do I lazy load on a view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view listing news items.

Is is possible to lazy-load them, so when I scroll to the bottom of the screen, it will load more news items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many modules available for your requirements. You will need to decide which module fits your requirements.

These are some useful modules.

1. [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll)
2. [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more)
3. [Image Lazyloader](https://www.drupal.org/project/lazyloader)

Comment: There's also [Lazy-load](https://www.drupal.org/project/lazy) as of April 2018. It can be used to lazy load all images (field images & inline images). Could be easily used with Views without making any changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that: views infinite scroll. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll